# JavaFX: apply multiple shadow layers to a single css element

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to add a layered shadow effect similar to the code below, in javafx through css?

```
#myButton>.text {
text-shadow:0 0 5px #228DFF, 0 0 10px #228DFF, 0 0 15px #228DFF, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 35px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
}
```